# Maven JSP taglib archetype

Tags: java, jsp, maven, taglib, maven-archetype

I am creating a custom JSP tag. It's quite easy to write the Java class, as well as defining the TLD.

My problem is that I don't know how to configure Maven to build a proper JAR file. I want to use my tag in other web applications as a Maven dependency. Perhaps JAR packaging isn't the best. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Define "proper jar file". Not sure how else you'd package it.

Comment: I mean: I'd like to have Maven build such a JAR, that once included in other module's dependencies it will be properly handled during deployment of that module - that is - the tags will land in proper webapp directiories etc.

Comment: JSP-based tags? Not sure that's possible; jars are self-contained units and different bits don't "land" anywhere when included in a project.

Comment: @DaveNewton I mean a custom Tag library as in [link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/WebAppDev3/). How am I supposed to develop a tag then?

Comment: If it's just a Java-based tag then you shouldn't need to do anything in particular, just put your TLD at the root of your classpath.

Comment: That's what I want to automate: to put the java tag class in one place and tld in other..

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you want the TLD somewhere else besides the root of your classpath, where it will be discovered automatically?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5246/discussion-between-queequeg-and-d-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, running:

```
mvn package
```

Will compile your code and generate a 'proper' JAR file that can then be used by other projects.

More likely, you are wondering how this new JAR file can be added to other Maven projects by simply adding a dependency in the POM file. In order to accomplish this, you will need to place your project's JAR and POM file in a repository. This repository can be the local repository on your machine (in which case any one else will have to also install the package) or in some online repository (perhaps using a tool like Artifactory to maintain your own).

If you have access to an online repository, you use the `distributionManagement` part of the POM to specify it and then run:

```
mvn deploy
```

To deploy to it.

To install your project in your local repository use:

```
mvn install
```

For more, dealing specifically with custom JSP tags using Maven, see this [JSP custom tag example](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/720/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already used Maven a little bit, and it's all fine when I have i.e. a library that I use in Java classes of a Servlet. This situation is different, because the tag files must be placed in non-standard locations after deployment.. To be precise I need a custom tag to use in my JSPs that run on Liferay Portal..

Comment: Assuming you are building your web project with Maven, it really should just be a matter of declaring the dependency. See the link I added to my answer.

Comment: It's working like a charm. Please highlight the link, it's VERY useful!